# Pppd upstart script

Tags: vpn, upstart

I am creating an upstart conf to manage different VPN connections. The problem is that if the `pppd` daemon dies, `initctl` still think it is `start/running`.

This is my current `vpn.conf`

```
description "VPN clients"

instance $vpn
export vpn

pppd call $vpn
```

How can I make upstart understand that if the daemon dies the status is not running any more ?

When the client is running the process tree looks like this:

```
root     30502     1  0 Aug11 ?        S      0:00 pppd call 162.xx.yy.42
root     30503 30502  0 Aug11 ?        S      0:00  \_ sh -c pptp   162.xx.yy.42 --nolaunchpppd
root     30504 30503  0 Aug11 ?        S      0:07      \_ pptp 162.xx.yy.42 --nolaunchpppd
```

Comment: Just a reminder: PPTP has been known to be insecure for well over a decade. Nobody should be using it anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton could you please send more information about why is insecure by definition (Now I see information for example here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45509/are-there-any-known-vulnerabilities-in-pptp-vpns-when-configured-properly )? What alternative do you suggest ?

Comment: Something like IPsec with IKEv2 and certificates, (never IKEv1) or OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Upstart script for PPTP, I think you can fix yours based on mine.
You need to replace the `[PEER-NAME]` with the name of the peer file in the directory `/etc/ppp/peers`:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop  on runlevel [016]
respawn
exec /usr/sbin/pppd nodetach persist call [PEER-NAME]
```